# custom directive why does only the unbind hook get called?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have this custom directive:

```js
Vue.directive("supermodel", {
  unbind: function (el, { arg }, vnode) {
    console.log('unbind')
    console.log(arg);
    console.log(vnode.context);
  },
  update: function(){
    console.log('here')
  },
  inserted: function() {
    console.log('insert')
  },
  componentUpdated: function() {
    console.log('componentUpdated')
  },
  bind: function(){
    console.log('bind')
  }
});
```

When I put the directive on a [bootstrap-vue `<b-modal>`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal) only the `unbind` hook in my directive gets called, and it gets called when the modal opens and again when closed. Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing the params with the function call in bind

```
function (el, binding, vnode)
```

So it is unable to get the element to bind to and the propeties for binding.

Comment: Just in case I did try this, but no change

Comment: Because of the way that js function calls work, I would not expect this to make a difference though